# Setting Windows 10 Powershell Line Background and Prompt Color Permanently

Tags: windows, powershell, colors, settings

I want to set the background color of the powershell prompt line, and color of the prompt text itself permanently.

I use the function:

```
function Set-ConsoleColor ($bc, $fc) {
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = $bc
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fc
    Clear-Host
}
Set-ConsoleColor 'black' 'green'
```

And that works. However when I type in any command afterwards, especially if it is not a valid command, it goes back to the default blue and white. In other words 'PS C:\Users\me' goes back to white text with a blue background, when it just was changed to a green text on a black background.

How can I set the line background and the prompt color permanently in Windows 10 Powershell?

Comment: Take a look at `Get-PSReadLineOption`

Comment: @LotPings. That doesn't seem to work. It  doesn't change the background color of the prompt, nor the text color

Comment: Well those settings interact, to know what ***your*** prompt function does, take a look at `(gcm prompt).Definition` or define your own and put it into the relevant `$profile`. My own one for example has a two line prompt with a ruler and red text when elevated.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it without code is to launch a PowerShell console, Click on the PowerShell Context Menu icon in the top left corner and select **Defaults**. Click on the **Colors** tab, change the **Screen Background** color, and **ok**. Then close and restart the PowerShell Console.

Comment: Important: "close and restart the PowerShell Console". Was changing colors and nothing happened. It helps to read until the end! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the Dutch text. But its as simple as launching PowerShell, right clicking the title-bar and selecting 'Properties'.
[image]

From there you get neat little settings window from which you can select 'Colors' to... well change the colors:

[image]

It's as simple as that. No need to around with commands or config files somewhere deep in your OS!

Answer (score 0):

This is something related to the $$PROFILE.

You can modify your script to add the changes permanently , FG and BG colors to -> $file     `notepad $PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost`

```
function Set-ConsoleColor ($bc, $fc) {
$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = $bc ;  out-file $PROFILE
$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fc ;  out-file $PROFILE -append
Clear-Host}
```